# Using a variable to dynamically load a class

Tags: php, singleton, classloader

I have decided to use the singleton pattern for my application. It makes the most sense to me. However, just when I feel like I have made some progress I run into another wall.

I have a load function. The load function does the following.

Check if class has been previously loaded. 
- If so - return $class::get_instance();
- Otherwise - look for class in various places - if found - return $class::get_instance(); - else return error.

Before adopting the Singleton pattern I was instantiating classes with the load class.

In the controller I would have this.

```
$session = $this->load->library('session');
```

The load class would then find the file and return..

```
return new $class_name;
```

I hoped that the in changing the method of loading classes it would be a tweak to a few lines but these tweaks are generating syntax errors.

```
return $class_name::get_instance();
```

Is there a way to write the line above without the syntax error?

Comment: you didn't get `syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in ...` by any chance?

Comment: You might want to change *loaded* to *instantiated*. Loading sounds more like you just want to `include` the class file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using call_user_func?

```
return call_user_func(array($class_name, "get_instance"));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Answer (score 1):

Try [`call_user_func()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

```
call_user_func(array($classname, 'getInstance'));
call_user_func($classname .'::getInstance'); // As of 5.2.3
```

In addition, if you want to build a class manager that handles arbitrary object creation for you, have a look at the [Symfony Dependency Injection Components](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/) and also at this very easy to follow [presentation on SlideShare about Dependency Injection with PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/fabpot/dependency-injection-with-php-and-php-53) in general.